# Why does plt.cla() only work on one of the plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a program that has two different plots at the same time:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()


for i in range(100):
    x = np.arange(i, i + 50, 0.2)

    plt.cla()

    for subplotId in range(1, 3):
        plt.subplot(2, 1, subplotId)
        plt.ylim(-100, 100)

        y = np.tan(x)
        plt.plot(x, y)

    plt.pause(0.1)
```

However, `plt.cla()` only seems to work on the second plot.
The first plot seems to get 'squished': [image: Plots]
How do I clear both plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `plt.cla()` only works on the current subplot.
To fix the problem you need to run it after each subplot, like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()


for i in range(100):
    x = np.arange(i, i + 50, 0.2)
    #don't put plt.cla() here

    for subplotId in range(1, 3):
        plt.subplot(2, 1, subplotId)
        plt.cla() # put it here so that it runs for each subplot
        plt.ylim(-100, 100)

        y = np.tan(x)
        plt.plot(x, y)

    plt.pause(0.1)
```

I hope this helps.